# How to UPDATE a table in phpmyadmin using another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi i am having real problems with my database
 i have two tables

```
GameID and GameGenre
```

**GameID** Has the following Fields

```
Name, age rating, genreid, gid, platformid
```

**GameGenre** has

```
gid and genreid
```

So here is a an example in the game ID field we have

```
Name        Age Rating   genreid    Platform ID   Gid
Dead Space    16         Horror     PS3,xbox360     1
```

in the game genre field we have

Gid 1 
Genre ID Horror

IF i change the genre-id field to horror and adventure in the game-genre table how do i get it to update the GameID field with that information ?

I have tired using a relation and forgin keys with the `genreid` fields but it changes
every field with that assoicated genre I want to to only change the one field associated with the specific `gid`.

Comment: The database design confuses me a little bit. You have a `GameID` table with a `genreid` and then additionally you have a table with a `genreid` which you link to the `GameID` table with `gid`.  Am I right, and if yes whats your goal?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use triggers (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

I'd provide an example, but really couldn't understand your database design. It's better to provide create statements in such cases.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `membership` AFTER INSERT ON `gamegenre`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE gameid
SET genreid = genreid + NEW.genreid 
WHERE id = NEW.gid_id;
END;$$

Comment: tried using a trigger keeps coming up with invalid syntex if someone could please give me an example it would be great

Comment: @Michael Please provide create statements for further help. And if you encounter an error message - provide it too, it'd be easier for everybody. I can only guess what you tried to do with such trigger otherwise.